# JNI methods are not calling when application comes foreground

Tags: android, java-native-interface, jnienv

I am using JNI in my application... When application launches it works fine and JNI logs are getting printed .. But once application went background and comes foreground after using some other application JNI Logs are not printing and methods are not getting called..

Can anyone suggest me a solution?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You need to provide some code before anyone could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Would you give more specific info about your JNI design?
First thing need to check...
Are you building JNIcode as shared library.So Check in logs JNI_Unload is getting called when Application is going in background.

Second thing need to check...
Check in Application going in backgroud ..Shared Library getting unloaded by Application.

Third Thing need to check...
Your JNI code is caching properly jvm and JNIEnv variable.

Comment: thanks for reply... it happens only if go background from my application and using more than 10 application and again come to my application..

Comment: when i check with logs, i could not see anything related to JNI_Unload...But how to check that Shared Library is getting unloaded?

Comment: @PM16..In your jini code Implememet the JNI_OnUnLoad function(check JNI reference APIs).. it helps out to check out the root cause of unloading .Also need to check you app state is running or not.

Comment: when it happens my app is removed from Recent app list automatically.. but when i click the desktop icon, application opens at the screen i seen last.. but if i do any jni call functionalities nothing happens... even the logs  i written for debugging are not printed..

Comment: Thank you.. I found what is wrong.. my shared library is getting unloaded by application.. but how to again load this??? by using System.loadLibrary(libName) ?

Comment: yes,this is the java API tp use/load library...System.loadLibrary(libName).

Comment: I tried by calling System.loadLibrary(myLibName).. but still getting same problem :(